# How to post nested json using angular js in form

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-data

How to POST Item Object using angularjs?

My simple java class:

```
@Entity
public class ProductionOrder implements Serializable {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Status status;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID")
    private Item item;
    private int plannedQty;
    private Date plannedDate;
    private String description;

//getters setters enum
```

My angular controller:

```
'use strict';

App.controller('PoController', ['$scope', 'PoService', function($scope, PoService) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.order = {id: null, status: null, item:null , plannedQty: null, plannedDate: '', description:''};
    vm.orders = [];


    vm.fetchAllOrders = function () {
        PoService.fetchAllOrders()
            .then(
                function (d) {
                    vm.orders = d;
                },
                function (errResp) {
                    console.error('Error while fetching production orders!');
                }
            );
    };

    vm.createOrder = function (item) {
        PoService.createOrder(item)
            .then(
                vm.fetchAllOrders,
                function (errResponse) {
                    console.error('Error while creating production order');
                }
            );
    };

    vm.fetchAllOrders();

    vm.submit = function () {
        if (vm.order.id === null) {
            console.log('Saving new order', vm.order);
            vm.createOrder(vm.order);
         } else  {
            console.log('Sth wrong with adding new order');
         }
            vm.reset();
    };

    vm.reset = function () {
        vm.order = {id: null, status:null, item: null, plannedQty: null, plannedDate: '',  description:''};
        $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
    };

}]);
```

And this is my angular service:

```
'use strict';


App.factory('PoService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    return {

        fetchAllOrders: function () {
            return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/po/all')
                .then(
                    function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    },
                    function (errResponse) {
                        console.error('Error while fetching production orders');
                        return $q.reject(errResponse);
                    }
                );
        },

        createOrder: function (item) {
            return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/po/add', item)
                .then(
                    function (res) {
                        return res.data;
                    },
                    function (errRes) {
                        console.error('Error while adding production order');
                        return $q.reject(errRes);
                    }
                );
        }
    };

}]);
```

In html I have simple form:

```
       <div class="ui main text container", ng-controller="PoController as ctrl">
        <form class="ui form" ng-submit="ctrl.submit()" name="myForm">
            <h4 class="ui dividing header">Production order information</h4>
            <div class="field">
                <label> </label>
                <div class="two fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.order.id" placeholder="Production order id">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.order.item" placeholder="Item id">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h4 class="ui dividing header">Status:</h4>
            <select class="ui dropdown" ng-model="ctrl.order.status">
                <option value="CREATED">CREATED</option>
                <option value="PLANNED">PLANNED</option>
                <option value="DONE">DONE</option>
            </select>

            <h4 class="ui dividing header">Planning information</h4>
            <div class="field">
                <label> </label>
                <div class="two fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.order.plannedQty" placeholder="Quantity">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.order.plannedDate" placeholder="Enter date RRRR-MM-DD">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </br>
            <div class="field">
                <label>Description</label>
                <textarea ng-model="ctrl.order.descritpion"></textarea>
            </div>


            <div class="asbutton" id="button">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="ui primary button" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
                <button class="ui button" type="button" ng-click="ctrl.reset()" ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine">
                    Reset
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And when i type for example: 1. It means I want to create realtion with item with 1 id. In Terminal I see error:

2016-06-12 16:06:13.906  WARN 10057 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.prod.domain.Item] from String value ('2'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2b8fb852; line: 1, column: 25] (through reference chain: com.prod.domain.ProductionOrder["item"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.prod.domain.Item] from String value ('2'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2b8fb852; line: 1, column: 25] (through reference chain: com.prod.domain.ProductionOrder["item"])

How could I POST nested json similar to this:

```
item: {id: 6}
```

Comment: something to do with int vs string in your JSON. check that id value isn't being sent as  a string (e.g. `{id: "6"}`)

Comment: @Tsar in console i see: description: ""
id: null
item: "2"
plannedDate: "2016-01-01"
plannedQty: "10"
status: "CREATED" in js console